# Sistema de abas em jQuery com reload da página

Tags: jquery

Bom galera, montei um sistema de abas bem simples, com a ajuda do pessoal do Stack.

Bom ele funciona 100%, porém tem alguns casos que eu preciso fazer com que a página seja atualiza ao quicar na aba1. Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
onclick='location.reload();
```

Coloquei o evento na aba-1 porém nada acontece. Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Lembrando que não e para todas as abas 1 atualizar, apenas em alguns casos específico, então preciso de alguma forma de informar qual aba vai dar reload na página.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab-content').each(function(i) {
    var tabTitle = $(this).data('tab-title');
    var current = $(this).hasClass('current') ? "current" : "";
    var newTab = $('<li class="tab-link"></li>');
    newTab.html(tabTitle)
      .addClass(current)
      .attr('data-tab', $(this).attr('id'));
    $('ul.tabs').append(newTab)
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.tabs li', function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  });

})
```

```css
.tabs-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #616161;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
  color: #484848;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F65314;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
.tab-link:hover {
  color: #FBBC05;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs"></ul>
  
  <div id="tab-1" data-tab-title="Tab 1" class="tab-content current" onclick='location.reload();'>
    bla bla bla
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" data-tab-title="Tab 2" class="tab-content">
    bla bla bla
    <br>bal bal balbla bla bla
    <br>bal bal bal
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" data-tab-title="Tab 3" class="tab-content">
    bla bla bla 2
    <br>bal bal balbla bla bla
    <br>bal bal bal
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar um  switch no evento de click, esse deve conter o id da tab atual, se for a escolhida a case efetua alguma ação.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab-content').each(function(i) {
    var tabTitle = $(this).data('tab-title');
    var current = $(this).hasClass('current') ? "current" : "";
    var newTab = $('<li class="tab-link"></li>');
    newTab.html(tabTitle)
      .addClass(current)
      .attr('data-tab', $(this).attr('id'));
    $('ul.tabs').append(newTab)
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.tabs li', function(e) {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    console.log(tab_id);
    switch(tab_id){
      case 'tab-1':
      alert('Aqui vc pode reiniciar');
        location.reload(); 
      break;
    }
    
    $('.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  });

})
```

```css
.tabs-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
}
ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #616161;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.tabs li.current {
  color: #484848;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #F65314;
}
.tab-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}
.tab-content.current {
  display: block;
}
.tab-link:hover {
  color: #FBBC05;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs-container">
  <ul class="tabs"></ul>

  <div id="tab-1" data-tab-title="Tab 1" class="tab-content current" onclick='location.reload();'>
    bla bla bla
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" data-tab-title="Tab 2" class="tab-content">
    bla bla bla
    <br>bal bal balbla bla bla
    <br>bal bal bal
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" data-tab-title="Tab 3" class="tab-content">
    bla bla bla 2
    <br>bal bal balbla bla bla
    <br>bal bal bal
  </div>
</div>
```